# Express the Radical Simplified form $-\sqrt{27k^7q^8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Can someone help me with this problem and explain the steps I need help and I have a test for this type of question. I need to simplify 
$$-\sqrt{27k^7q^8}$$

Comment: Do you mean $-\sqrt{27k^7q^8}$?

Comment: yes please help?

Answer (score 1):

Anything which is a square you can take out of the radical.  In particular, $27k^7q^8$ contains a lot of squares:

- $27 = 9 \cdot 3$ ($9$ is a square--it is the square of $3$)
- $k^7 = k^6 \cdot k$ ($k^6$ is a square--it is the square of $k^3$)
- $q^8$ is a square (it is the square of $q^4$)

So you can write
$$
27 k^7 q^8 = (3 \cdot k^3 \cdot q^4)^2 \cdot 3 \cdot k
$$
Then
$$
-\sqrt{27k^7q^8}
= -\sqrt{(3 \cdot k^3 \cdot q^4)^2 \cdot 3 \cdot k}
= -3 k^3 q^4 \sqrt{3k}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But can you explain why K^6 is a square of k^3

Comment: Because $(k^n)^m = k^{nm}$.

Comment: @Crissy The square of $k$ is $k \cdot k$, the square of $k \cdot k$ is $k \cdot k \cdot k \cdot k$, and so on.  If you square $k^3$, you double the number of $k$s.  So you now have $6$ $k$s, which is $k^6$.